# What sort of service is Bitcoinica?

Tags: websites, services, bitcoinica

What sort of service is [Bitcoinica](https://www.bitcoinica.com/) (or was before it was closed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoinica):

> An exchange that enables leveraged speculation in its
>   contract-for-difference (CFD) market against the Bitcoin to USD
>   (BTC/USD) exchange rate.
>
> The service charges no trading fees but instead earns from the trading
>   spread -- similar to how forex trading functions.

This was a powerful (and risky) service to provide to traders as leveraging allowed them to invest in more bitcoins than what they owned, and the contract-for-difference market allowed traders to take a position (gamble?) on exchange rate movements.

There appeared to be a strong appetite for such a service, because it grew in popularity very quickly - it was [first mentioned on bitcointalk.org in Sep 2011](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=42267) and by March 2012 was large enough to be holding BTC43,000 ([when it was first hacked](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3642/516)).